# Continuity of addition in topological vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, continuity

It is easy to see in a topological vector space $X$, since  addition is continuous then, “ for any elements $x$ and $y$ in $X$ and any sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$, then $x_n+y_n \rightarrow x+y$. Is the converse true, ie, if for any elements $x$ and $y$ and any sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ approaching $x$ and $y$ respectively, then The addition is continuous ?

Comment: If $X$ is a metric space, then obviously the converse is true. I'm not sure about the case when $X$ is a locally convex space (meaning the topology is determined by seminorms).

Comment: @Kakashi If $X$ is locally convex then addition is clearly continuous.

Comment: @Jochen Yes you are right. Disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general this does not hold:
Consider the cocountable topology on $\mathbb R$ (ie. the closed sets are exactly the countable sets or $\mathbb R$ itself). Then there are no non-trivial sequences in $\mathbb R$ at all. But addition is not continuous, since
$\{(x, -x): x \in \mathbb R\} = \{(x, y): x+y = 0\}$ is not closed in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.